# Self defined Function to replicate a Number and return a List?

Tags: haskell

```
 myreplica :: (Num a,Ord a) => a -> b -> [b]
 myreplica num val 
         | num <= 0 = []
         | otherwise = [val] ++ myreplica (num-1) val
```

The above function takes two values Num and Val and returns a List L = [val,val...num times].The code works fine for 0 and positive values but when i give input like

```
"ghci> " replicate' -1 123 

<interactive>:72:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (i -> a -> [a])
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
   When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall i a a1.
            (Num i, Num a1, Num (i -> a -> [a]), Num (a1 -> i -> a -> [a]),
             Ord i) =>
            i -> a -> [a]
```

I get the following error message.How can I make it work for negative numbers?
**Why do we need (Num a,Ord a) constraint?**

Comment: The above is parsed as `(replicate') - (1 123)` where the last part means "function `1` applied to argument `123`", whcih makes no sense. The type checker then complains that `replicate'` has not a numeric type: `Num (i->a->[a])` has no instance.

Comment: @chi thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the negative number with parentheses i.e. `myreplica (-1) 123`. However, you might instead want to add a special case using `error` for negative numbers in first argument, since it doesn't make sense to repeat something a negative number of times.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZLJH64460)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.Can you explain about why we have to use (Num a,Ord a) ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need `(Num a, Ord a)`, but it is reconmedable, also notice that it is better to use the `(:)`function instead of '(++)' as follows:

```
 myreplica :: (Num a,Ord a) => a -> b -> [b]
 myreplica num val 
         | num <= 0  = []
         | otherwise = val : myreplica (num-1) val
```